# How to read file and write into different files according to different paragraphs

Tags: c

my original code is used for reading and copying one file into another (the content contains several paragraphs and each paragraph is separated by a line break ). But now I need to read the file and write it into several different files(each file contains just one paragraph). But I don't know how to do it, hope anyone can give a favor.
the original code is shown below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void) {
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
char ch, file_name[10];

FILE *fp;
FILE *fa;

printf("enter the name of file\n");
gets(file_name);
fa=fopen("write.txt","w");
fp=fopen(file_name,"r");

if(fp==NULL)
{
    perror("error while opening the file. \n");
    exit(1);
}

printf("the contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);
while((ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
    printf("%c",ch);
    fprintf(fa,"%c",ch);

}



fclose(fa);
fclose(fp);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: What is special about paragraphs? The line break, or the empty line?

Comment: should be a empty line, sorry

Comment: Then I guess you're going to have to test for `'\n''\n'`, two newlines immediately after each other.

Comment: yes, but still no idea, how to recognize it and split the content :(

Comment: Really? How about, in your `fgetc()` loop: `If (ch == '\n') if ((ch = fgetc()) == '\n' ) /*change output FILE* to next file*/ else putchar('\n');`

Comment: what criteria are you planning to use for recognition of a paragraph break?  What criteria are you planning to use for the generation each successive (including the first) output file name?

Comment: use a two state machine implementation I.E. initial state is first state.   if char read is '\n' and in first state then: transition to second state.  if char read is not '\n' then transition to first state.  If char read is '\n' and in second state then:handle new paragraph (no state change)  the final no state change will handle multiple blank lines giving multiple empty output files

Comment: Change `char ch` --> `int ch`.  `fgetc()` returns an `int` with maybe 256 different `unsigned char` values and `EOF`.  If code saves one of  257  into `char`, which has 256 different values, something will not compare correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    char ch, file_name[10];

    FILE *fp;
    FILE *fa;
    FILE *fc;
    FILE *fd;
    FILE *fe;
    FILE *ff;
    printf("enter the name of file\n");
    gets(file_name);
    fa=fopen("write0.txt","w");
    fp=fopen(file_name,"r");
    fc=fopen("write1.txt","w");
    fd=fopen("write2.txt","w");
    fe=fopen("write3.txt","w");
    ff=fopen("write4.txt","w");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        perror("error while opening the file. \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("the contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);
    while((ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
        printf("%c",ch);
        fprintf(fa,"%c",ch);
        if(ch=='\n'){
            if((ch=fgetc(fp))=='\n'){
                        goto a;
            }
                    }
    }
    a:

    while((ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
            printf("%c",ch);
            fprintf(fc,"%c",ch);
            if(ch=='\n'){
                if((ch=fgetc(fp))=='\n'){
                            goto b;
                }
            }
        }
        b:
        while((ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
            printf("%c",ch);
            fprintf(fd,"%c",ch);
            if(ch=='\n'){
                    if((ch=fgetc(fp))=='\n'){
                         goto c;
                            }
            }
        }

        c:

        while((ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
                    printf("%c",ch);
                    fprintf(fe,"%c",ch);
                    if(ch=='\n'){
                            if((ch=fgetc(fp))=='\n'){
                                 goto d;
                                    }
                    }
                }

         d:
         while((ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
                    printf("%c",ch);
                    fprintf(ff,"%c",ch);

                }

    fclose(fa);
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fc);
    fclose(fd);
    fclose(fe);
    fclose(ff);
    return 0;
}
```